# How do we create a Merge request in Smartgit client?

Tags: smartgit

Can someone help me with the step by step to create a merge request on smartgit client?
I'm not able to find the option for that.

Comment: Are you referring to GitLab merge requests?

Comment: @mstrap Yes. GitLab merge requests.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for GitHub -- it's almost identical: https://docs.syntevo.com/SmartGit/Latest/GitHub-integration.html